# Dreamweaver synchronize code with design in split view?

Tags: dreamweaver

When I am in split view in Dreamwever CS6 and edit something in design view the code is not updated automatically and I have to click in code area so it appears.

I swear it worked in CS5 version. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I assume it's up to date and you've restarted the program?

Comment: @DaveRook yes :(

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things which may help, depending on your situation

> Code view is updated automatically when you make changes in Design view. However, after making changes in Code view, you must manually update the document in Design view by clicking in Design view or pressing F5.

And on the same page (source below)

> Refresh Design View
>       Updates the document in Design view so that it reflects any changes you made in the code. Changes you make in the code don’t
>   automatically appear in Design view until you perform certain actions,
>   such as saving the file or clicking this button.

[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7beaa.html#WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7be2a)

Answer (score 2):

Stop using Split View.

Instead

1. Click the Design View Button
2. Choose Window > Code Inspector
3. Drag the Code Inspector Window so it Docks below Design View
4. Choose Window > Workspace Layout > New Workspace. Give it a name such as My Layout and save.

Now when you make changes in Code Inspector and then Click on Save, the Design View is automatically refreshed. You no longer need to refresh before saving.

Any changes you make in Design View are automatically visible in the Code Inspector.

This worked in Dreamweaver CS4 but should work in other versions.

Comment: Thanks for this!  This is how Dreamweaver's split view used to be by default once upon a time.  Glad to finally get it back.